# convexity of negative log likelihood under constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The negative log-likelihood function

\begin{align}
\text{min}_B -log|\Sigma^{-1}| + \text{tr}[(Y-XB)\Sigma^{-1}(Y-XB)]
\end{align}

is a convex optimization with respect to $\Sigma^{-1}$. However, if I have a constraint:

\begin{equation}
\Sigma = (J + BU')W(J + BU')'
\end{equation}

is this still a convex optimization problem? Except for B, the rest of the quantities are known.

Comment: In your constraint: What are parameters and what are optimization variables?

Comment: @gerw I have updated my question.

Comment: I do not have any idea, but I would guess that this is not convex.